# mvt vector tiles on showing on MapboxGL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, geodjango, vector-tiles

I followed 
https://medium.com/@mrgrantanderson/https-medium-com-serving-vector-tiles-from-django-38c705f6

to serve the mvt tiles to the mapbox from geoDjango.

With running query

```
   cursor.execute("SELECT ST_AsMVT(tile) FROM (SELECT osm_id, building, ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, TileBBox(%s, %s, %s, 3857)) FROM  nepal_khokanabuildings ) AS tile", [zoom, x, y])
```

as my model project is ESPG:3857

The Vectors don't seem to load up on the map, the api request is working fine. 
I also tried serving vector files from Geoserver no luck either.

Here is my JS File

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
zoom: 12,

    center: [85.294688,27.634106],

});
    var mapillarySource = {
      type: 'vector',
      tiles: [
       'http://0.0.0.0:8000/nepal/api/v1/data/nepal/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'
        ],
      minzoom: 0,
      maxzoom: 14
  };

map.on('load', function() {

  map.addSource('mapillary', mapillarySource);
  map.addLayer({
      'id': 'mapillary',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'mapillary',
      'source-layer': 'water',
      'paint': {
                "fill-color": "#00ffff"

      }
  });
});
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of problems that can manifest themselves as "my layers don't show".

You can check each of these things:

- is the layer being created before the map is ready? (wait for `"load"` event)
- are the correct tile requests being generated?
- are those requests succeeding?
- are they returning actual .pbf files?
- do they contain data in the right location, and in the right projection?
- do they contain a layer with the name you expect? ('water' in this case)
- do they contain data of the type you expect? (polygons in this case)

I am curious about the 0.0.0.0 host, but also suspect that the layer name may not be right.

If your tile requests are succeeding, you can try using https://stevage.github.io/vector-inspector/ to inspect them, although you may have issues with that page being served on HTTPS and your local tiles being on HTTP.

Comment: I cloned your repo it work pbf api works on your application. I was able too get all the vector datas.

I changed the source-layer to "building" still not luck

Comment: So you can verify that tiles with the right data in the right layer name is making it into the browser, but it's not rendering at all? Any errors in the console? Are you adding the layer before the map is ready by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Use Following ,

```
"id": "postgis-tiles-layer",
"source-layer": "default",
```